# SpriteKit Issue With SKShader Animation In Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, shader

For the life of me, I cannot understand why this shader animation is not running. Any help is appreciated. Please see the code below... the shader displays correctly, but does not animate. Thank you.

NOTE: Xcode 9.4.1, Swift 4.1, iOS 11.4

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    static let marquee: SKShader = {
        let shader = SKShader(
            source: "void main() {" +
                "float np = mod(a_path_phase + v_path_distance / u_path_length, 1.0);" +
                "vec3 hsb = vec3(np, 1.0, 1.0);" +
                "vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);" +
                "vec3 p = abs(fract(hsb.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);" +
                "vec3 rgb = hsb.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), hsb.y);" +
                "vec4 df = SKDefaultShading();" +
                "gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, df.z);" +
            "}"
        )
        shader.attributes = [SKAttribute(name: "a_path_phase", type: .float)]
        return shader
    } ()

    private let beat: TimeInterval = 0.05
    private var phase: Float = 0

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let node = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 256, height: 256), cornerRadius: 16)
        node.fillColor = .clear
        node.strokeColor = .white
        node.strokeShader = GameScene.marquee
        node.lineWidth = 8
        node.glowWidth = 4
        node.run(
            SKAction.repeatForever(
                SKAction.sequence(
                    [
                        SKAction.wait(forDuration: beat),
                        SKAction.run() { [weak self] in
                            if let weak = self {
                                weak.phase = fmodf(weak.phase + Float(weak.beat), 1)
                                node.setValue(SKAttributeValue(float: weak.phase), forAttribute: "a_path_phase")
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                )
            )
        )
        addChild(node)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Did you ever happen to figure this one out? So far, for me, the attribute value does not seem to arrive at the shader, the shader seems to always get value = 0.0; It's as if the node.setValue(,forAttribute:) command is being ignored. Could it be an iOS bug, or am I missing something? I hope it is not a bug. I hope I am missing something.

Answer (score 3):

I was also having trouble with `.setValue(forAttribute:)`. It did not seem to work. Upon investigation, my conclusion is that...

I believe `SKShapeNode.setValue(forAttribute:)` is not working.

The fact that `SKSpriteNode.setValue(forAttribute:)` did work correctly under the same set of conditions led me to conclude that it was almost surely some bug in iOS in `SKShapeNode`.

> The fact was that any `SKAttribute`s I might set in
>   `SKShapeNode.fillShader` or `SKShapeNode.strokeShader` kept their
>   values set to `0.0` no matter what I did.
>
> However, the same did not happen with `SKSpriteNode.shader`.

So I had to find a way to circumvent this bug. 
Some sort of hack. 
Fortunately, in my case, I did find a way.

And fortunately, it seems to be enough to solve your problem too.

---

What you can do, in this case, is to pass the value of your ***phase*** as one of the components of the `strokeColor`, for example, the **red** component.

To do this you will have to normalize the ***phase*** to values between `0.0` to `1.0`. 
You can pass a *phase* ***multiplier*** using a *shader.uniform* to help denormalize it.

Then read the ***phase*** value inside the shader from `SKDefaultShading().x`, (the red component).

> Make sure to set the **alpha** component of the
>   `strokeColor` to `1.0`, for `SKDefaultShading()` will have its color
>   component values already premultiplied by its alpha.

Now, because your *strokeColor* is already being used to pass the ***phase***, you can pass the actual color of the stroked line as a *vec4 shader.uniform*.

---

- In my case, I also made use of `u_time` to help in performing my
  animation. Stuff like `fract(u_time)` can be very useful.

---

Here is how the corrected code might look like:

### > NOTE: There is a much simpler solution. Look by the end of this post.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    private typealias Me = GameScene
    static let phaseMultiplier: Float = 1000

    static let marquee: SKShader = {
        let shader = SKShader(
            source: "void main() {" +
                "float red = SKDefaultShading().x;" +
                "float phase = red * u_phase_multiplier;" +
                "float np = mod(phase + v_path_distance / u_path_length, 1.0);" +
                "vec3 hsb = vec3(np, 1.0, 1.0);" +
                "vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);" +
                "vec3 p = abs(fract(hsb.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);" +
                "vec3 rgb = hsb.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), hsb.y);" +
                "vec4 df = u_stroke_color;" +
                "gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, df.z);" +
            "}"
        )
        let white = vector_float4.init(1, 1, 1, 1)
        shader.uniforms = [
            SKUniform(name: "u_phase_multiplier", float: Me.phaseMultiplier), 
            SKUniform(name: "u_stroke_color", vectorFloat4: white)]
        return shader
    } ()

    private let beat: TimeInterval = 0.05
    private var phase: Float = 0

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let node = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 256, height: 256), cornerRadius: 16)
        node.fillColor = .clear
        node.strokeColor = .white
        node.strokeShader = Me.marquee
        node.lineWidth = 8
        node.glowWidth = 4
        node.run(
            SKAction.repeatForever(
                SKAction.sequence(
                    [
                        SKAction.wait(forDuration: beat),
                        SKAction.run() { [weak self] in
                            if let weak = self {
                                weak.phase = fmodf(weak.phase + Float(weak.beat), 1)
                                let phase = weak.phase / Me.phaseMultiplier
                                node.strokeColor = SKColor.init(red: phase, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                )
            )
        )
        addChild(node)
    }
}
```

***NOTE:*** I did not compile the code above posted. I should serve merely as a sketch.

---

> The day after this post, I found out that *attribute* parameters are not supposed to be used in *fragment shaders*, only in *vertex shaders*.

Take a look at StackOverflow question:
[In WebGL what are the differences between an attribute, a uniform, and a varying variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537879/in-webgl-what-are-the-differences-between-an-attribute-a-uniform-and-a-varying)

> The SDK documentation of `SKAttribute` and `SKAttributeValue`, however, seem to suggest that there may be no direct relation between "SKAttributes" and actual shader *attribute* parameters. They just seem to be named the same.

---

### Simpler Solution:

In the end, however, there is never any need to make use of any hack like the one I show here.

> All that needs to be done is to set the value of a *uniform* through `SKShader.uniformNamed("u_phase")?.floatValue = phase`, instead of using `.setValue(forAttribute:)` just as **jmdecombe**, correctly, later pointed out.

I will keep my answer here for reference, as it presents an unconventional solution to a problem.

Comment: Hi, it's been a while but I give that code a look and indeed the solution was to use uniforms instead of attributes, then it worked.

Comment: Namely, the line shader.attributes = etc. had to become: shader.uniforms = [SKUniform(name: "a_path_phase", float: 0.0)], then the line node.setValue etc. had to become: node.strokeShader?.uniformNamed("a_path_phase")?.floatValue = weak.phase

Comment: What you are telling me here is that you decided to write to a Uniform rather than to an Attribute, which I did not realize could be possible. Both of our "alternative" ways to accomplish our needs do seem to confirm one thing though, which is that there is a bug in SKShapeNode.setValue(,forAttribute:).